# CKEditor Filter does not persist text after modifying

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, plugins

I wrote a filter class that strips out certain tags from the user input in the editor. For example it uses a regular expression to remove `<span>` tags of a certain class.

The steps I took were:

- Create a custom module
- In the module, create a class that extends `FilterBase`
- Implement the abstract method `process()`
- Return modified text wrapped in a `FilterProcessResult` object

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8).

The filter is called when I save a page with a WYSIWYG on it, and I've confirmed that it executes the `FilterBase::process()` function I wrote. I've also confirmed that it strips out the tags I need it to remove as expected before it returns.

Even though the modified text is correct, it doesn't seem to persist in the content of the WYSIWYG. For example, if I reload the edit page, I'll see that the tags that I removed are still there. What is causing this issue? How can I get it to persist on save?

On closer inspection, the filtered text only shows when I'm viewing the page I've created, but not when I access the WYSIWYG text programatically.

I fit matters, the filter is of type `FilterInterface::TYPE_HTML_RESTRICTOR`.

Comment: `The filter is called when I save a page` I haven't worked with CKEditor, so I have no exp on this area, but I think should be called when viewed rather than save a page.

Comment: @NoSssweat You may be right because it does redirect to the page view immediately after saving.